# Convert Complex Excel to XML

Tags: xml, excel

after researching for the past three days and compiling a hackneyed version of an Excel-to-XML converter, it's time I come to the forum for help because I can't get exactly what I need. There's some good code here, though, so anyone that needs it can grab it.

I have two converters: 1) Excel-to-XML (in VB) and 2) XML-to-Excel (in C# below). The latter successfully creates an a functional Excel file, albeit one that won't convert back as nicely formed XML.

The issue, I believe, is two-fold. The first problem has to do with the fact that the file resulting from the XML-to-Excel conversion isn't including the  and  tags, and I'm not sure how to get that to happen. The second problem is that the Excel-to-XML converter is formatting the XML elements strangely (see below).

The original sample XML file is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="practice.xsd">
<Person>
  <FirstName>Oscar</FirstName>
  <LastName>Banda</LastName>
</Person>
<Person>
  <FirstName>Steven</FirstName>
  <LastName>Richter</LastName>
</Person>
<Person>
  <FirstName>Luis</FirstName>
  <LastName>Contreras</LastName>
</Person>
<Person>
  <FirstName>Elias</FirstName>
  <LastName>Cooper</LastName>
</Person>
 </Data>
```

This converts into a two-column Excel file with column headers for first and last names, but without recognition of the  and  tags anywhere. Thus, going the other way gets me (also notice the wrong element names, and strange naming formats):

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
     <NewDataSet>
   <Your>
    <First_x0020_Name>Oscar</First_x0020_Name>
    <Last_x0020_Name>Banda</Last_x0020_Name>
  </Your>
  <Your>
    <First_x0020_Name>Elias</First_x0020_Name>
    <Last_x0020_Name>Cooper</Last_x0020_Name>
  </Your>
  <Your>
    <First_x0020_Name>Steven</First_x0020_Name>
    <Last_x0020_Name>Richter</Last_x0020_Name>
  </Your>
  <Your>
    <First_x0020_Name>Luis</First_x0020_Name>
    <Last_x0020_Name>Contreras</Last_x0020_Name>
  </Your>
</NewDataSet>
```

The VB I'm using is the following:

```
    Public Function ExcelToXMLConverter(excelFile As String)
    Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim ds As System.Data.DataSet
    Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim source As String = excelFile
    Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & source & ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"

    'get Table Name
    MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select *  from [Practice$]", MyConnection)
    MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Your")

    'Fill dataset with the data
    ds = New System.Data.DataSet()
    MyCommand.Fill(ds)
    ds.WriteXml(IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(source).ToString() & "\" & IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(source) & ".xml")
    MyConnection.Close()

    Return (ds)
End Function
```

This probably has something to do with the MyCommand.TableMappings.Add function, but I'm not sure how to make that work without using the strings I have already.

EDIT: I realize now that the "your" in the tablemappings.add would have to be changed to "Person" to get the correct element names, but this doesn't explain why the "First/Last Name" elements are being returned in a strange format. I'd also rather not hard-code this string.

Furthermore, in wondering how I can get this changed programmatically, I'm including my XML-to-Excel converter (in C#) to see if anyone can suggest a way to include the  and  elements in the resulting Excel file such that when I convert the other way, Excel-to-XML, I get the original document.

```
   public String XMLtoExcel(string xmlInputFile)
    {
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        // create Excel 
        Excel.Application myApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook myWbk = myApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        Excel.Worksheet myWst = (Excel.Worksheet)myWbk.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        // load xml file
        string input = xmlInputFile;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        XmlReader xmlFile;
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
        xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(input, settings);
        ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);

        // write root into excel
        //XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        //doc.Load(input);
        //XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
        //myWst.Cells[1, 1] = root.Name;

        // write data in to excel
        int col, row;
        int i = 1;
        int counter = ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count;
        for (col = 0; col <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; col++)
        {
            myWst.Cells[1, i].value = ds.Tables[0].Columns[col].ColumnName;
            myWst.Cells[1, i].EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;
            i += 1;
        }

        i = 2;

        int k = 1;
        for (col = 0; col <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; col++)
        {
            i = 2;
            for (row = 0; row <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; row++)
            {
                myWst.Cells[i, k].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[row].ItemArray[col];
                i += 1;
            }
            k += 1;
        }
 }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

The column heading for your Excel spreadsheet contains spaces in the names, like "First Name".  (0020 is the ascii code for a space).  When you query these columns back from excel, you should alias them without the space.  Try this VB code:

```
'get Table Name
MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString)
MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select [First Name] AS FirstName, [Last Name] AS LastName  from [Practice$]", MyConnection)
MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Person") 'You already figured this one out
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the spaces removed and "Person" added programmatically?

Comment: My query (above) aliases the column names to remove the spaces and the table mapping "Person" was already figured out by you. Do you mean that you don't want to use a query to alias the columns via the query for some reason?

Comment: Thanks, by the way.

What I meant was that I'd rather not write "select [First Name] ..." because it's likely that I'll be adding other columns and would want them all called out without spaces. Doing it the way you offered could end up being quite the task if there's a lot of columns.

Comment: Ah. I understand. I think the spaces are automatically added by Excel. It is supposed to improve the readability of the spreadsheet. The extra spaces are inserted between a lowercase followed by an uppercase. You could make your columns all upper or all lower case, but it would probably make it look ugly. You could also go to the extra effort of re-opening the XML after it was generated and doing a Replace() call to remove all "_ x0020 _". It would be a little hackish, but it would be a little more maintainable.